# function in lapply not working when applied to some columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, say

```
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(5, NA, 1, 6),
                   x2 = c(4, 3, 0, NA),
                   c = c('a', 'b', 'a', NA)); data

  x1 x2 c
1  5  4 a
2 NA  3 b
3  1  0 a
4  6  NA NA
```

I want to replace the NAs by 0 on x1 and x2 columns only, so I use the lapply function as below:

`data[c("x1","x2")] <- lapply(data[c("x1","x2")], function (x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0}); data` 
This does not work as the output is:

```
 x1 x2 c
1  0  0 a
2  0  0 b
3  0  0 a
4  0  0 NA
```

I then tried to create a separate function

```
fxNAtoZero <- function (x) {
  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
  return(x)
}
```

and if I use this like below:

```
data[c("x1","x2")] <- lapply(data[c("x1","x2")], fxNAtoZero); data
```

it works, but the first case does not. I do not understand why the function created on fly is not working in lapply?

Comment: You don't `return(x)` in the first case. Another option would be `data[c("x1","x2")][is.na(data[c("x1","x2")])] <- 0`

Comment: @joran: then it would replace NAs in c also, I have edited the example df

Comment: @markus: how would the return look like in lapply? Like this?
lapply(data[c("x1","x2")], function (x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0 return(x)})

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your first attempt just return the last line of the function in `lapply`, that is 0:

```
lapply(data[c("x1","x2")], function (x) {x[is.na(x)] <- 0})
$x1
[1] 0

$x2
[1] 0
```

while your second attempt return explicitely return the entire vector after changing the NA, because you used `return`. You should prefer if you want to use lapply:

```
lapply(data[c("x1","x2")], function (x) {ifelse(is.na(x),0,x) })
```

because `ifelse` does return a vector of the same length as the initial one.

Comment: And a non-loop, vectorized route: `data[c("x1","x2")] <- ifelse(is.na(as.matrix(data[c("x1","x2")])), 0, as.matrix(data[c("x1","x2")]))`

Comment: @Parfait I I think you could simplify this to: `data[c("x1","x2")][is.na(data[c("x1","x2")])] <- 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `dplyr` verbs to transform your data, and replace `NA`'s for the desired cases. This is perhaps a bit more readable than using `lapply`, but note that the variables are converted to strings since that is the format for variable c.

```r
data <- data.frame(x1 = c(5, NA, 1, 6),
                   x2 = c(4, 3, 0, NA),
                   c = c('a', 'b', 'a', NA),
                   id = c(1:4)) # create with row id, for spread

data %>% gather(k,v,-id) %>% 
  mutate(v=ifelse(is.na(v) & k!='c',0,v)) %>% # replace NA's based on conditions
  spread(k,v) %>% select(-id)

     c x1 x2
1    a  5  4
2    b  0  3
3    a  1  0
4 <NA>  6  0
```